# linq to sql: 2 where's not working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am doing this in LINQ TO SQL:

```
var query = Database.ExtendedUsers.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.Acolumn >= 4);
```

which generates the correct SQL syntax (with where clause).
If I add a 2nd where, it is ignored:

```
var query = Database.ExtendedUsers.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.Acolumn >= 4);
query.Where(x => x.AnotherColumn.Equals(2));
```

The second where clause isn't added to the SQL query. 
**What am I doing wrong?**

Basically, I want to dynamically add where's

```
query.Where(...);
query.Where(...);
query.Where(...);
query.ToList(); /: result
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Where` returns new `IQueryable` implementation (with added proper nodes in Expression Tree that is used to generate SQL). So basically, you just need to assign result back to the `query` variable:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.AnotherColumn.Equals(2));
```

**Editor: please do not change my post and add code I didn't have posted (add comment instead).** The OP wants to use where dynamically (f.e. based on conditions). Sample:

```
var query = Context.MyTable.Where(tbl => tbl.Col > 4);
if (someConditionThatCannotBeEvalutedInLinqToSql)
{
   query = query.Where(2)tabl => table.Col2 == 5);
}
```

So, `Where(x => x.Acolumn >= 4 && x.AnotherColumn.Equals(2))` is not always solution and I don't believe that is what the OP needs.

Comment: This works, but very strange thing: if I do that in a function, it doesn't work. I have: var query = Database.Users.Select(x=>x);
myFunction(query);
and myFunction is then adding the where clauses. this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @PoeHaH your function `myFunction` should return also query. Then: `query = myFunction(query)`.